# RMI Callbacks using a single port

Tags: java, rmi

How can I reduce the number of overall ports used by RMI from N (where N = number of RMI UnicastRemoteObjects) to 2 + N?

Allow me to explain further. I have a system which is using RMI to perform client-server communication. There are two interfaces; we shall call them Client and Server to keep things simple. The RMI registry runs in the same JVM as Server, and is bound to some port (say 4000). Server is exported as a UnicastRemoteObject with no port number, and is bound to an anonymous port as per the no-args constructor.

When a Client starts up, it calls a void hello(Client client) method on the Server implementation which it gets from a lookup on the registry. The Client implementation passed in is also a UnicastRemoteObject; giving us bi-directional communication between Client and Server over the two interfaces. The problem is that the UnicastRemoteObject in the Client is also listening on its own anonymous port.

That means that in order to have N clients, I need to have 1 + 1 + 3 * N ports availble; 2 + N of which are listening, and 2 * N of which are ephemeral. (Registry + Server Instance + One listening port per client, Ephemeral port per client, Ephemeral port per server). We usually have around 30 clients, giving 92 ports. I believe I can get this down to 32 ports (1 + 1 + the ephemeral port for each client), but I can't see how to do it with pure RMI.

I am willing to accept other solutions which do not require RMI, but also do not require that we re-write our interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear what the problem is here. Exported RMI objects will all share the same port number by default, unless you have written non-compliant server socket factories. You can specify the port number to be used when constructing or exporting them as described in the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObject`. You can use the same port for your objects and the Registry when starting the latter in your JVM. Your 92 ports don't make much sense as a resource count even if accurate, as they are distributed across all the server and client hosts.

Comment: I should have clarified that the reason for the 92 ports is that the system needs to be able to cope with remote clients, but for 99% of cases the clients will actually be running on the same machine.

I am unsure how the exported objects can all share the same port if they're running in different VMs though?

Comment: @Andrew So you need one listening port for all remote objects including the registry, and one ephemeral port for outbound connections to each of them. Sounds like 1+N to me.

Comment: One listening port for all remote objects, so one for the registry, one for the server, and one for each client. That's 2 + N. You then need the ephemeral port for each client to the server. That's another N. You finally need the ephemeral port for the server to each client. That's another N. So 2 + N listening ports, and 2 N ephemeral ports.

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Oh, yes. I put listening in the first line... I meant overall ports. My apologies.

Comment: @Andrew One shared port for the Registry and the server, so 1+N listening ports. But even 91 ports isn't a lot. I'd be a lot more concerned about the 31 JVMs.

Comment: Oh believe me, I'm already more than concerned about that. Unfortunately getting that number down is a project for another day... or month. Today's project is to placate the client about the number of ports the services use. From where I'm sitting, it's not a matter of "why do you need us to less ports?" as "yes sir, I'll make it use less ports".

Comment: @Andrew Well you can't. The main issue is the ephemeral outbound ports, and you can't do anything about them except eliminate the callback architecture. That's just how TCP works. I have many more ports in use between my Apache HTTPD, four Tomcats, OpenLDAP, MySQL, etc. How come the client is counting ports already?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20480/discussion-between-andrew-and-ejp)

Comment: I am in GMT-11 so that may not work. The silver bullet you need would be a bidirectional RMI protocol that could carry client and callback traffic at the same time. It doesn't exist. Note that this isn't just an RMI problem: the same port usage would occur if you were using CORBA, or SOAP, or plain TCP. The port usage is tripled by the callbacks.

Comment: NB You don't need an ephemeral port in the server to client direction.